# Send push from Parse with html/php form

Tags: php, parse-platform

I can seem to figure out how to send push notification from my website insted of logging in to the dashboard on Parse.com.  I have made a simple HTML form to send the pushes from, but i can't figure out the rest.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<form>
<h1> Send push</h1>
 <h3>Push message</h3>
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30">
</textarea>
<h3>Who will reccive push (channel)?</h3>
 <p><h4>Select both or only one</h4>
<input type="checkbox" name="Kristiansand" value="kristiansand"> Kristiansand
<input type="checkbox" name="Egersund" value="egersund"> Egersund

<input type="submit" value="Send push">

</form>
</html>
```

Comment: I missed it when i copy pasted the code.

Comment: Please paste in your correct `<form>` starting tag, just `<form>` is wrong.

Comment: You need to send push notification to the user who is selected in the form. Am I correct?

Comment: To all the users suscribed to channel egersund, kristiansand, or both.

Comment: How do you send the push? Please specify the route or the cloud function you use to perform such action.

Comment: Right now am using parse.com controllpanel.